# Generate chart dynamically using json data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Json return data as :

```
[{"id_":1,"mobile_id":4,"mobile_name":"Nokia","order_quantity":2,"orders_date":"2015-01-01T00:00:00"
},{"id_":2,"mobile_id":1,"mobile_name":"Moto G","order_quantity":6,"orders_date":"2015-01-05T00:00:00"
},{"id_":3,"mobile_id":2,"mobile_name":"IPhone","order_quantity":3,"orders_date":"2015-01-06T00:00:00"]
```

I have managed to generate chart dynamically but using hardcoded data as below:

`Updated`

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "api/test/getdata",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data) {
            //Test(data);
            ////make chart
            // prepare jqxChart settings
            var settings = {
                title: "Fitness & exercise weekly scorecard",
                description: "Time spent in vigorous exercise",
                padding: { left: 5, top: 5, right: 5, bottom: 5 },
                titlePadding: { left: 90, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 10 },
                source: data,//returned from ajax.
                categoryAxis:
                    {
                        dataField: 'orders_date',
                        showGridLines: false
                    },
                colorScheme: 'scheme01',
                seriesGroups:
                    [
                        {
                            type: 'spline',
                            columnsGapPercent: 10,
                            seriesGapPercent: 0,
                            valueAxis:
                            {
                                minValue: 0,
                                maxValue: 100,
                                unitInterval: 10,
                                description: 'Time in minutes',


                            },
                            series: [
                                    { dataField: 'mobile_name', dataField: 'price' },

                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'column',
                            seriesGapPercentage: 5,
                            valueAxis:
                                {


                                    displayValueAxis: false,

                                },
                            series: [
                                   { dataField: 'Moto G', displayText: 'Moto G' },
                                   { dataField: 'Iphone', displayText: 'Iphone' },

                            ]
                        }
                    ]
            };

            // select the chartContainer DIV element and render the chart.
            $('#chartContainer').jqxChart(settings);
        }
    });
```

But I would like to use json data which is returned from ajax call instead of using hard-coded data. So the ajax call returns data successfully as shown above but how can they be shown in the chart?

after updating code according to Cyril's answer the chart look like :[image]

So how to show Iphone, Nokia, and Moto G in separate lines and every phone with its price, for example in IPhone line show only Iphone price and Nokia in serparate line with its own price. In addition, Order date needs to be in short format.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/test/getdata",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data) {
            Test(data);
            //make chart
            // prepare jqxChart settings
            makeMyChart(data);
    });
    function makeMyChart(data){
       var settings = {
        title: "Fitness & exercise weekly scorecard",
        description: "Time spent in vigorous exercise",
        padding: {
            left: 5,
            top: 5,
            right: 5,
            bottom: 5
        },
        titlePadding: {
            left: 90,
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 10
        },
        source: data, //returned from ajax.
        categoryAxis: {
            dataField: 'Date',
            showGridLines: false
        },
        colorScheme: 'scheme01',
        seriesGroups: [{
            type: 'spline',
            columnsGapPercent: 30,
            seriesGapPercent: 0,
            valueAxis: {
                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 100,
                unitInterval: 10,
                description: 'Time in minutes'
            },
            series: [{
                dataField: 'jhr',
                displayText: 'jhr'
            }, {
                dataField: 'png',
                displayText: 'png'
            }, {
                dataField: 'ked',
                displayText: 'ked'
            }]
        }]
    };

    // select the chartContainer DIV element and render the chart.
    $('#chartContainer').jqxChart(settings);
    }
   }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: for sure your answer gave some help, but it needs some changes due to result is not as expected, I have updated question code and attach it with output chart.